# glsl shader in Quartz Composer

Tags: opengl, glsl, vertex-shader, quartz-composer, glsles

I was trying to make [this](http://glsl.heroku.com/e#15857.2) shader working in Quartz Composer

When I copy this shader's code to `Fragment Shader` in the `GLSL Shader` patch, 
`error: input of fragment shader 'surfacePosition' not written by vertex shader`

So what do I need to fill in the vertex shader instead of the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quartz Composer's default vertex shader uses `gl_TexCoord[0]` to pass the texture coordinate from the vertex shader to the fragment shader.

So, in the fragment shader, you could remove `varying vec2 surfacePosition;`, and in line 16, replace `surfacePosition` with `gl_TexCoord[0].xy-0.5`.